# Storing Facebook friends profile pictures for my Offline Android App

Tags: android, jquery, sqlite, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an Android App which is using the users Facebook friends profile pictures.

**Using: Jquery(HTML5 & JS) - Phonegap(cordova) - Facebook APIs**

**Using**:

```
document.getElementById('profilePic').src = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+response.id+"/picture?width=150&height=200";
```

Now problem is when my app has internet connection then its fine to use this. Please suggest that how to store the profile pictures so that app can work even offline, if there is no internet connection.

Need to access the users Facebook friends profile pictures offline.
Internet search suggests use:

1. localstorage
2. sqlite
3. filesystem folder

Please suggest how I can store the images for faster access and can be stored locally.